# How to move button left inside table

Tags: html, css, webforms

I have this ASP code:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="PervousResultsList" runat="server" EnableViewState="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="row1">
                <table style="cursor: pointer; width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="4">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/pushpinred.png" runat="server" Width="32"
                                Height="32" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <td rowspan="10">
                        <input type="button" id="ddd" value="B" style="height:30px" />
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>text:</td>
                        <td rowspan="4">
                            <h1 style="color: gray"><%# Eval("Text") %></h1>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="hidden">
                        <td>text:</td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Text") %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="hidden">
                        <td>X:</td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Lon") %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="hidden">
                        <td>Y:</td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Lat") %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

I bind a repeater in server side to the data source:

```
PervousResultsList.DataSource = _marker.GetPervousResults();
PervousResultsList.DataBind();
```

Here is how it looks in view:

[image]

How can I move button B to the left that it will looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<table style="cursor: pointer; width: 100%">
    <asp:Repeater ID="PervousResultsList" runat="server" EnableViewState="False">
        <itemtemplate>
            <div class="row1">
                <tr>

                    <td rowspan="10">
                        <input type="button" id="ddd" value="B" style="height:30px" />
                    </td>

                    <td rowspan="4">
                        <h1 style="color: gray"><%# Eval("Text") %></h1>
                    </td>

                    <td>text:</td>

                    <td rowspan="4">
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/pushpinred.png" runat="server" Width="32"
                                   Height="32" />
                    </td>


                </tr>

                <tr class="hidden">
                    <td>text:</td>
                    <td><%# Eval("Text") %></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hidden">
                    <td>X:</td>
                    <td><%# Eval("Lon") %></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hidden">
                    <td>Y:</td>
                    <td><%# Eval("Lat") %></td>
                </tr>

            </div>
        </itemtemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

Comment: What changes have you made?

Comment: table definition outside of the repeater and rows should be repeated only. Also I changed the column (td) order

Answer (score 0):

I Think what you could do is take the `table` definition outside of the repeater and define your table rows right.

Try this and let me know if it helps (I didn't test the code):

```
<table style="cursor: pointer; width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Header</td>
        <td>Header</td>
        <td>Header</td>
        <td>Header</td>
        <td>Header</td>
        <td>Header</td>
    </tr>
    <asp:Repeater ID="PervousResultsList" runat="server" EnableViewState="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" id="ddd" value="B" style="height:30px" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/pushpinred.png" runat="server" Width="32" Height="32" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h1 style="color: gray"><%# Eval("Text") %></h1>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("Text") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("Lon") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("Lat") %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

In the code the repeater will create only the table rows in each iteration. You define the table and header outside of the repeater because otherwise you would be creating a new table for each iteration. Aditionally, a `<tr>` defines a row.

Comment: @Michael Are you binding the repeater server side? Can you update your code to show how it is both in ASP and C#?

Comment: @Michael show the full server side code please. You only shared 2 lines. :)

Comment: @Michael Also I corrected a mistake in the first `td` inside the repeater. Take a look at it.